I use Kotlin DSL + BuildSrc to construct buildTypes, but I can't run it normally
Many signature files are configured in the original project. Signatures are distinguished by buildtypes. When debugging, many corresponding configuration items can be seen, and debugging can be performed quickly on different devices.



In the new project, multiple modules are used. In order to make all modules share this configuration, I imitated the project code of https://github.com/android/nowinandroid and configured it using buildSrc. Currently, the corresponding buildTypes appear in Android studio, but it cannot be run.

fun configureFlavors(
    commonExtension: CommonExtension<*, *, *, *, *, *>,
    flavorConfigurationBlock: ProductFlavor.(flavor: XcFlavor) -> Unit = {},
) {
    commonExtension.apply {
        flavorDimensions += FlavorDimension.xcApexIIF.name
        productFlavors {
            XcFlavor.values().forEach {
                create(it.name) {
                    dimension = it.dimension.name
                    flavorConfigurationBlock(this, it)
                    if (this@apply is ApplicationExtension && this is ApplicationProductFlavor) {
                        if (it.applicationIdSuffix != null) {
                            applicationIdSuffix = it.applicationIdSuffix
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


@Suppress("EnumEntryName")
enum class FlavorDimension {
    xcApexIIF
}


@Suppress("EnumEntryName")
enum class XcFlavor(val dimension: FlavorDimension, val applicationIdSuffix: String? = null) {
    midtest(FlavorDimension.xcApexIIF, applicationIdSuffix = ".midtest"),
}


fun configureBuildTypes(
    commonExtension: CommonExtension<*, *, *, *, *, *>,
    buildTypeConfigBlock :  BuildType.() -> Unit = {},
) {
    commonExtension.apply {
        buildTypes {
            XcSigning.values().forEach {
                register(it.name){
                    isMinifyEnabled = false
                    buildTypeConfigBlock(this)
                    if (this@apply is ApplicationExtension && this is ApplicationBuildType) {
                       signingConfig = it.signing
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

fun Project.configureSigningConfigs(
    commonExtension: CommonExtension<*, *, *, *, *, *>,
    signingConfigBlock :  ApkSigningConfig.(xcSig :XcSigning) -> Unit = {},
) {
    commonExtension.apply {
        signingConfigs {
            print("XC XcSigning size "+XcSigning.values().size)
            XcSigning.values().forEach {
                try {
                create(it.name) {
                    storeFile = project.file(it.storeFile)
                    print("XC XcSigning storeFile "+storeFile)
                    storePassword = it.storePassword
                    keyAlias = it.keyAlias
                    keyPassword = it.keyPassword
                    enableV2Signing = it.enableV2Signing
                    signingConfigBlock(this,it)
                    if (this@apply is ApplicationExtension && this is ApkSigningConfig) {
                        it.signing = this
                    }
                }
                }catch (e:Exception){
                    print("\nXC Exception = e ")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


@Suppress("EnumEntryName")
enum class XcSigning(
    val storeFile: String,
    val keyAlias: String,
    val keyPassword: String,
    val storePassword: String,
    val enableV2Signing: Boolean,
    var signing: ApkSigningConfig?
) {
    t1522("../signKeys/android13platform.keystore", "android", "androiddebugkey", "android", true,null),
  

The build was successful, but an error message will be displayed when running.

Executing tasks: [:midtest:assembleMidtestH0871] in project C:\yongchuan\apex\intelligent_inspection_factory

> Task :xc_build:xcbuild:checkKotlinGradlePluginConfigurationErrors
> Task :xc_build:xcbuild:compileKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :xc_build:xcbuild:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :xc_build:xcbuild:pluginDescriptors UP-TO-DATE
> Task :xc_build:xcbuild:processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :xc_build:xcbuild:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :xc_build:xcbuild:jar UP-TO-DATE

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':midtest:lintVitalReportMidtestH0871'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':midtest:midtestH0871CompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :xc_apex_base.
     Required by:
         project :midtest
      > No matching variant of project :xc_apex_base was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during compile-time, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '8.4.0', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'h0871', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.ProductFlavor:xcApexIIF' with value 'midtest', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' but:
          - Variant 'debugApiElements' declares a library for use during compile-time, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '8.4.0', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm':
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'h0871'
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.ProductFlavor:xcApexIIF (required 'midtest')
          - Variant 'debugRuntimeElements' declares a library for use during runtime, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '8.4.0', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm':
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'h0871'
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.ProductFlavor:xcApexIIF (required 'midtest')
          - Variant 'debugSourcesElements' declares a component for use during runtime, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '8.4.0', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm':
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug' and the consumer needed a library, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'h0871'
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.ProductFlavor:xcApexIIF (required 'midtest')
          - Variant 'releaseApiElements' declares a library for use during compile-time, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '8.4.0', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm':
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'h0871'
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.ProductFlavor:xcApexIIF (required 'midtest')
          - Variant 'releaseRuntimeElements' declares a library for use during runtime, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '8.4.0', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm':
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'h0871'
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.ProductFlavor:xcApexIIF (required 'midtest')
          - Variant 'releaseSourcesElements' declares a component for use during runtime, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '8.4.0', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm':
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release' and the consumer needed a library, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'h0871'
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.ProductFlavor:xcApexIIF (required 'midtest')

* Try:
> Review the variant matching algorithm at https://docs.gradle.org/8.7/userguide/variant_attributes.html#sec:abm_algorithm.
> No matching variant errors are explained in more detail at https://docs.gradle.org/8.7/userguide/variant_model.html#sub:variant-no-match.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.TaskDependencyResolveException: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':midtest:lintVitalReportMidtestH0871'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.getDependencies(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:68)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.TaskDependencyResolver.resolveDependenciesFor(TaskDependencyResolver.java:49)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNode.getDependencies(LocalTaskNode.java:148)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNode.resolveDependencies(LocalTaskNode.java:122)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultExecutionPlan.discoverNodeRelationships(DefaultExecutionPlan.java:182)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultExecutionPlan.doAddEntryNodes(DefaultExecutionPlan.java:154)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultExecutionPlan.addEntryTasks(DefaultExecutionPlan.java:129)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultExecutionPlan.addEntryTasks(DefaultExecutionPlan.java:121)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskNameResolvingBuildTaskScheduler.scheduleRequestedTasks(TaskNameResolvingBuildTaskScheduler.java:54)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTasksBuildTaskScheduler.scheduleRequestedTasks(DefaultTasksBuildTaskScheduler.java:72)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultTaskExecutionPreparer.lambda$scheduleRequestedTasks$0(DefaultTaskExecutionPreparer.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:31)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withReplacedLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:360)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$DefaultBuildProjectRegistry.withMutableStateOfAllProjects(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:240)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$DefaultBuildProjectRegistry.withMutableStateOfAllProjects(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:233)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultTaskExecutionPreparer.scheduleRequestedTasks(DefaultTaskExecutionPreparer.java:45)
    at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.lambda$scheduleRequestedTasks$0(VintageBuildModelController.java:76)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$inState$1(StateTransitionController.java:99)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$inState$2(StateTransitionController.java:114)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.inState(StateTransitionController.java:110)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.inState(StateTransitionController.java:98)
    at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.scheduleRequestedTasks(VintageBuildModelController.java:76)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController$DefaultWorkGraphBuilder.addRequestedTasks(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:404)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeWorkPreparer.lambda$scheduleRequestedTasks$0(DefaultBuildTreeWorkPreparer.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.lambda$populateWorkGraph$7(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:189)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildWorkPreparer.populateWorkGraph(DefaultBuildWorkPreparer.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkPreparer$PopulateWorkGraph.populateTaskGraph(BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkPreparer.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkPreparer$PopulateWorkGraph.run(BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkPreparer.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkPreparer.populateWorkGraph(BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkPreparer.java:67)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.lambda$populateWorkGraph$8(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:189)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$inState$1(StateTransitionController.java:99)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$inState$2(StateTransitionController.java:114)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.inState(StateTransitionController.java:110)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.inState(StateTransitionController.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.populateWorkGraph(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:189)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildWorkGraphController$DefaultBuildWorkGraph.populateWorkGraph(DefaultBuildWorkGraphController.java:169)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultBuildController.populateWorkGraph(DefaultBuildController.java:76)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph$DefaultBuildTreeWorkGraphBuilder.withWorkGraph(DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeWorkPreparer.lambda$scheduleRequestedTasks$1(DefaultBuildTreeWorkPreparer.java:41)
...


BUILD FAILED in 1s
5 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 4 up-to-date
XC XcSigning size 7XC XcSigning storeFile C:\yongchuan\apex\intelligent_inspection_factory\signKeys\android13platform.keystoreXC XcSigning storeFile C:\yongchuan\apex\intelligent_inspection_factory\signKeys\t1621_movfast.keystoreXC XcSigning storeFile C:\yongchuan\apex\intelligent_inspection_factory\signKeys\t1622platform.keystoreXC XcSigning storeFile C:\yongchuan\apex\intelligent_inspection_factory\signKeys\t1625_pdd.keystoreXC XcSigning storeFile C:\yongchuan\apex\intelligent_inspection_factory\signKeys\p0823_key.jksXC XcSigning storeFile C:\yongchuan\apex\intelligent_inspection_factory\signKeys\h0831_platform.keystoreXC XcSigning storeFile C:\yongchuan\apex\intelligent_inspection_factory\signKeys\h1071_platform.keystore


I have solved this problem myself. I defined it in the app module, and I also need to define it in the library's gradle, otherwise an error will be reported.
class XcApexBaseFlavorsLibraryConventionPlugin : Plugin<Project> {
override fun apply(target: Project) {
    with(target) {

        val androidExtension = extensions.getByType<LibraryExtension>()
        androidExtension.buildTypes.configureEach {
            enableAndroidTestCoverage = true
            enableUnitTestCoverage = true
        }
        extensions.configure<LibraryExtension> {
            configureSigningConfigs(this@configure)
            configureBuildTypes(this@configure)
        }
    }
}

}
